# Split Folders and sub folder to Data Frame in R

Tags: r

I have list of FolderPaths (as a Data.Frame Column) that I need to split and add 1,2 level folder names to my Data.Frame. I can split the path using

```
F1<-strsplit(DF$FolderPath,"\\\\")
```

This gives me a list of lists with uneven number of elements.(Folder tree has different depths) so using matrix(unlist(F1)) wouldn't work as indicated in other answers to similar questions. I need to select each element 1 and 2 in lists and add it to my data.frame, something like:

```
DF$FolderLevel1<-magicfunction using F1
DF$FolderLevel2<-magicfunction using F2
```

Please note I am not looking for writing a custom function. Just couldnt figure out the syntax.

Comment: some sample data would help here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `length` of each list element to the maximum and than do `rbind`.

```
F1 <- strsplit(c("a", "a\\b", "a\\b\\c"),"\\\\")
do.call(rbind, lapply(F1, "[", 1:max(lengths(F1))))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "a"  NA   NA  
#[2,] "a"  "b"  NA  
#[3,] "a"  "b"  "c"
```

Comment: Yes this works but is rather slow. For 500,000 rows, strsplit is working its magic under a second. Adding this operation takes forever. Is there a faster solution?

Comment: @MuratErenturk Maybe the updated version is faster.

Comment: Yes, much better. Thanks a lot.